# composer-rest-server Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When I try `composer-rest-server -c acme-admin@test-bna` I get this output:

```
Discovering the Returning Transactions..
Discovered types from business network definition
Generating schemas for all types in business network definition ...
Generated schemas for all types in business network definition
Adding schemas for all types to Loopback ...
Added schemas for all types to Loopback
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1485:7)
    at module.exports.promise.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/cli.js:143:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

I am actually doing a udemy course about how to setup a hyperledger multi org network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is showing that the port `3000` is busy.

`EADDRINUSE` means some process is already running on that port.

You can find the process by using the following command:

```
sudo ss -lptn 'sport = :3000'
```

It will return you process id, then you can kill it by:

```
sudo kill -9 process_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that some process was running on the port 3000. This command fixed it.

```
fuser -n tcp -k 3000
```