# composer-rest-server Error: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I installed and startet my business network. Now I want to do `composer-rest-server -c admin@test-network` but I get the following output:

```
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Discovering the Returning Transactions..
Discovered types from business network definition
Generating schemas for all types in business network definition ...
Generated schemas for all types in business network definition
Adding schemas for all types to Loopback ...
Added schemas for all types to Loopback
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1485:7)
    at module.exports.promise.then.then (/home/dany/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/cli.js:143:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

The funny thing is, that everything worked fine before. Then I restarted the fabric and reinstalled the bna file and now I get this error. Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [composer-rest-server Unhandled 'error' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647469/composer-rest-server-unhandled-error-event)

Comment: This querstion was already asked by you previously and answered also, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not stopped your script properly that's why this error is coming. This error comes when your port is already occupied and you are trying to start something on same port. So you can kill process on this port then it should work fine.

If you are using linux OS then this command might help you.

```
fuser -n tcp -k 3000
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem